# Is this reasoning for the integral correct?

Tags: calculus

I am trying to solve a physics problem that is stated as followed:
Find the velocity of an object dropped from an infinite distance onto Earth. To solve that you find the gravitational energy (work done on the object during the acceleration by Earth) and equate that to the kinetic energy of the object at the time it crashes into Earth (distance = radius of Earth). My reasoning is as follows:

The force exerted by one mass onto another is:

$$F = G\frac{mM}{r^2}.$$

To get the work done (gravitational potential energy) I integrate with respect to $r$:

$$W = \int G\frac{mM}{r^2} \, dr,$$ but because I need the total work from infinity to the radius of Earth $R$ I take the definite integral

$$\int_\infty^R G\frac{mM}{r^2} \, dr$$ which is equal to $$GmM\left [ -\frac{1}{r} \right ]_\infty^R.$$ Because the limit $\lim_{r\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{r}=0$    , I can write it as

$$W=-G\frac{Mm}{R}$$

To solve the problem I equate $\Delta E_\text{pot}=\Delta E_\text{kin}$ ($E_\text{kin} = \frac{1}{2}mv^2$), and rearrange for the velocity. Is that reasoning mathematically correct? Because when I enter the integral into Wolfram Alpha it says the integral from $R$ to infinity doesn't converge.

Comment: A distance of zero would be inside the center of the earth, if it crashes into the earth's surface that happens at the radius of earth, so the final distance is just the radius of earth

Comment: Yes sorry, that's correct I also calculated it this way but I missed it when typing the equations in Latex. Thanks for your correction!

Comment: Yep, with that correction the integral does converge, also the reasoning looks correct. The only other thing is that you need a negative sign for your energy relation as the gain in kinetic energy comes from a decrease in potential. This will take care of the negative sign when square rooting to find v

Comment: And with that correction the problem should go away, as [the integral from $R$ to $\infty$ converges.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5BG*m*M%2Fr%5E2,%7Br,Infinity,R%7D%5D)

Comment: @arkeet Thank you very much! That was a really stupid mistake haha.

Comment: The work is positive $\left(\,> 0\,\right)$: $\vec{F}\cdot\mathrm{d}\vec{r} > 0$.  [W & A did't fine](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5B(-G+M+m%2Fr%5E2),%7Br,Infinity,R%7D%5D)

Comment: $$
{1 \over 2}\,mv_{Earth}^{2} = {GMm \over R} = mgR\implies v_{Earth} = \,\sqrt{\,2gR\,}\, \approx 40,228.5\ \mathrm{Km \over h}.
$$
$v_{Earth}$ is the rapidity at the Earth Surface.

Comment: Maybe of interest http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/99737/what-will-be-the-velocity-of-a-comet-is-falling-to-the-earth-from-infinity-at-th

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bound of integration that you've written as $0$ should not be $0$ but should be the radius of the earth.